# Integrate cognito with spring-boot microservice

Tags: spring-boot, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

This could sound like a very noob question, so let me apologies first.

We have multiple lambda services (JavaScript) added that uses AWS cognito. I know that AWS cognito is majorly designed for authentication and authorisation in serverless architecture.

But now I have a microservice written in Java using spring boot which is deployed behind the AWS api gateway. The gateway is running as a proxy to the service's resources. So our client app authenticates users using cognito and used Authorization and api key to access our services which have AWS_IAM and api key authenticating every request to the service on the gateway.

To perform some tasks in the service cognitoIdentityId is required. In case of JS lambda services we receive it in the event json in its context field. But I could not find any way for the spring-boot service to receive it. Neither HttpSession nor HttpServletRequest have that info. Requests are not directly authenticated with the service so spring SecurityContext's principal is also empty/anonymous. The documentation on cognito with http services is very bleak and most of the discussions starts and ends with Lambda.

Can anyone point me to the right direction as how to get the id?

Thanks in advance.